# XGBoost in Databricks with Python

Tags: pyspark, xgboost, databricks

So recently I've been working around with Mlib Databricks cluster and saw that according to docs [XGBoost](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/01/07/introducing-databricks-runtime-5-1-for-machine-learning.html) is available for my cluster version (5.1). This cluster is running Python 2.

I get the feeling that XGBoost4J is only available for Scala and Java. **So my question is: how do I import the xgboost module to this environment without losing the distribution capabilites?**

A sample of my code is below

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
import xgboost as xgb # Throws error because module is not installed and it should

# Transform class to classIndex to make xgboost happy
stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="species", outputCol="species_index").fit(newInput)
labelTransformed = stringIndexer.transform(newInput).drop("species")

# Compose feature columns as vectors
vectorCols = ["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width", "species_index"]
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=vectorCols, outputCol="features")
xgbInput = vectorAssembler.transform(labelTransformed).select("features", "species_index")
```

Comment: Use Scala/Java if you want it to be distributed: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/mllib/third-party-libraries.html#xgboost-versions

Comment: I understand that, but with Python is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use spark-sklearn to distribute the python or scikit-learn version of xgboost, but that distribution is different than the xgboost4j distribution. I heard that the pyspark api for xgboost4j on databricks is coming, so stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant pull request, by the way, can be found [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/4656)

Comment: They are discussing about how and what will be added to pyspark. You can track the PR as well, for your convenience :)